# Need an alternative to BizTalk's XSLT generation

Tags: xslt, biztalk

At present we are using BizTalk as an XSLT generator. We map two XSDs together and then have BizTalk generate and XSLT that we use in another app. Shortly we will be getting rid of BizTalk and are on the hunt for a new program that will provide us this functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sad to hear you are loosing BizTalk.

I have tried MapForce from Altova, [more info here](http://www.altova.com/products/mapforce/data_mapping.html), it has similar functionality as BizTalk mapper.

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree with Martin. 
It's good that you are moving out of BizTalk if you are only using it as an XSLT generator.Using BizTalk just as an XSLT generator is like using YAG laser to cut through butter.(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRZ8TlvH2gc)